# Store functions to callback later in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift2

I have two functions, `func1` and `func2`. When one called, it should check if socket is connected. If socket is not connected it should append the function to handlers array and call it when socket will be connected.

```
func func1(data: NSData) {
    if(!socket.isConnected()) {
        //  how to do here ↓
        handlers.append(func1) 

        startConnectSocket()
        return;
    }
    socket.writeData(data, withTimeout: 0, tag: 0)
}

func func2(data1:NSData , data2:NSData) {
    if(!socket.isConnected()){
        //  how to do here ↓
        handlers.append(funky) 

        startConnectSocket()
        return;
    }
    socket.writeData(data1 + data2, withTimeout: 0, tag: 0)
}
```

When socket is connected, call all functions stored in handlers.

```
func onSocket(sock: AsyncSocket!, didConnectToHost host: String!, port: UInt16) {
    //  how to do here ↓
    for function in handlers {
        // call function
    }
}
```

Comment: Another way to consider doing this is using NSOperation with dependencies, which effectively implements the "promise" design.  Create an operation of connecting to the socket, another to perform func1, depending on first operation, and another to perform func2, which may be depending on func1 or just the socket operation.  For asynchronous, dependent operations it's often a nice architecture.  Ther's a good wwdc'15 talk on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save not only reference to `function` but also `data` parameter.
So you need to wrap it into the closure:

```
var handlers: [() -> ()] = []

func func1(data: NSData) {
    if(!socket.isConnected()) {
        handlers.append({ func1(data) }) 

        startConnectSocket()
        return;
    }
    socket.writeData(data, withTimeout: 0, tag: 0)
}

func func2(data1: NSData, data2: NSData) {
    if(!socket.isConnected()){
        handlers.append({ func2(data1, data2) }) 

        startConnectSocket()
        return;
    }
    socket.writeData(data1 + data2, withTimeout: 0, tag: 0)
}

func onSocket(sock: AsyncSocket!, didConnectToHost host: String!, port: UInt16) {
    for function in handlers {
        function()
    }
}
```

Comment: var handlers = [() -> ()]()    this line shows error
i fixed by change to 
var handlers:[()->()] = []
is there a better way?